# Увеличение отступа от линии подчеркивания в css

Tags: css

```css
span a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<span>
   <a href="#" >TEXT</a>
</span>
```

Как можно увеличить отступ от линии подчеркивания в `css`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

С `text-decoration: underline;` такого не получится сделать.
Нужно поставить `text-decoration: none;` и `border-bottom: 1px #цвет_ссылки solid;`. 
Вот хороший [совет](http://artgorbunov.ru/bb/soviet/20120510/) по теме.

Comment: Проблема возникнет только тогда, когда текст станет более чем в одну строку...тогда прийдёться потанцевать с бубном вокруг данной задачки

Comment: Проблема в том, что text-decoration оставляет оступы от букв до черты, а бордер подчёркивает всё, не глядя.

Answer (score 4):

для текста, но не блока использую: text-underline-offset

```
p {
  font-family: $main-font;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: $accent-color;

  text-decoration: underline;
  text-underline-offset: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В начале подумал, что не подходит вариант с `border`, так как заголовок может принимать ширину `100%`, и тогда бордер ничем не отличается от `<hr>`.

Прочитав следующий комментарий про `display:inline-block;`, помог сделать ширину заголовка, как бы по содержимому, остается только отцентрировать.

Дальше, поигравшись, и `inline-block` отставил в сторону, и применил `table`. Вот что получилось:

```css
display: table; /* ширина по тексту в заголовке */
border-bottom: 1px solid #8edfce; /* само подчеркивание */
line-height: 36px; /* высота строки, ну и, соответственно, отступ от подчеркивания */
```

Answer (score 1):

Я сам задался этим вопросом и нашел такой вариант:

```css
.nav_link:hover {
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  border-bottom: 1.2px solid #4d4d4d;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<span class="nav_link">TEXT<span>
```

Мне нужно было, чтобы после наведения на ссылку появлялось подчеркивание с отступом от строки `8px` и шириной в слово. `text-decoration: underline;` не давал такой возможности, а нижняя граница вуаля))

Answer (score 1):

Я справился с данной задачей следующим образом:

```
p {
   border-bottom: 1px solid black;
   height: 20px;
  }
```

Значение height будет определять на каком расстоянии от текста будет подчеркивание.
При необходимости также нужно прописать "text-decoration: none", чтобы не получилось две линии подчеркивания.

Comment: Ого, какой старый вопрос. Посмотрите на css-свойство `text-underline-offset`

Answer (score 1):

Вот так это можно реализовать.

```css
span a {
  text-decoration: underline solid red 0.5px;
  text-underline-offset: 10px;
}
```

```html
<span>
    <a href="#">TEXT</a>
</span>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться псевдоэлементом `::after`. Он позволяет более гибко настраивать линию под текстом.

```css
a {
  /* Уберем цвет и подчеркивание по умолчанию для ссылок */
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;

  display: inline-block;
}

a::after {
  /* Отступ между текстом и линией */
  margin-top: 5px;

  /* Толщина линии */
  height: 1px;

  /* Цвет линии будет таким же, что и цвет текста */
  background-color: currentColor;

  content: "";
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">TEXT</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Регулируемое подчеркивание **над текстом**:

```
text-decoration: underline 1px;
text-underline-offset: -100px;
```

Answer (score -2):

На мой взгляд лучше использовать display:inline-block